# If $G$ is a group and $A$ a subgroup of $G$ so that $ A \neq G$, and $ a \in A, g \in G, g \not \in A$ is then $ a*g \not \in A$?

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is a group and $A$ a subgroup of $G$ so that $ A \neq G $, and $ a \in A, g \in G, g \not \in A$ arbitrary is then $ a*g \not \in A$?

It is obvious that this can't be valid for all a's and g's, but can it be valid for some? 
Edit: I now realize that it is not possible because then $ {a} ^{-1} *a*g = g $ wpuld have to be an element of A.

Comment: Take $a=e$, the identity, and $g$ any element of $G\setminus A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $ag = b \in A$ then $g = a^{-1}b \in A$. So $ag$ will never be in $A$ if $g$ is not.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to show the contrapositive: For $a\in A, g\in G$, if $ag\in A$, then $g\in A$. This statement is equivalent to yours.

Assume $ag\in A$. Then $a^{-1}\in A$, and therefore $$A\ni a^{-1}\cdot ag=g$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $gA = \{ga:a\in A\}.$

You should explore two things:

1. When is it true that $gA = A$? More generally, if I have two elements $g,h\in G$, when is it true that $gA = hA$?
2. Prove that the collection of sets $gA$ form a partition of $G$; that is, that either $gA = hA$ or $gA\cap hA= \emptyset$.

To get you started about the way you can think about these questions, you might approach (1) as

> If $x\in gA$, then $x=ga$ for some $a\in A$. If $gA = A$, then $x\in A$. Thus we can rewrite $x= ga$ as $\dots$, and thus we know that $g$ $\dots$